# inserts not working and errors not showing

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert some information from 2 other tables to a single one by making 2 separated insert into select from and 1 insert into value, but these are not working and I don't know why.

Below is the code. The most important part is in the `else` block.

```
<?php

session_start();

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "projetopit");

    if (!$conn) {
    die("Conexão falhou: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST["confirmarconsulta"])){

        $nomemedico = $_POST["nomemedico"];

        $horario = $_POST["horario"];

        $cpfcliente = $_POST["cpfcliente"];

        $erros2 = array();

        if (empty($nomemedico) OR empty($horario) OR empty($cpfcliente)) {
            array_push($erros2,"É necessário que todos os campos sejam preenchidos! ");
        }

        if (strlen($cpfcliente)!=11) {
            array_push($erros2,"CPF inválido. ");
        }

        if(count($erros2)>0) {
            foreach ($erros2 as $erro) {
                echo "$erro";
            }
        }

        else{

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM dadoscadastrocuidador WHERE nome = '$nomemedico' /*AND SELECT * FROM dadoscadastrocliente WHERE cpf = '$cpfcliente'*/";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                          
            $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

            if ($user) {
                
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO agendamentos (nomemedico) SELECT nome FROM dadoscadastrocuidador WHERE nome = ?");
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO agendamentos (horario) VALUES (?)");
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO agendamentos (cpfcliente) SELECT cpf FROM dadoscadastrocliente WHERE cpf = ?");
                $stmt-> bind_param("sss", $nomemedico, $horario, $cpfcliente);
                $stmt->execute();

            }else{

                echo "Erro.";

            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Family Care - Login </title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='agendar.css'>
    <script src='agendar.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="/../agendar/agendar.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-div-card">
        <label for="">Nome do Médico:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nomemedico" id="nomemedicocss">
    </div>
    <div class="input-div-card">
        <label for="">Horário:</label>
        <input type="text" name="horario"  id="horariocss">
    </div>
    <div class="input-div-card">
        <label for="">Seu CPF:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cpfcliente" id="cpfclientecss">
    </div>
    <div class="input-button">
        <button id="btn-submit-cadastro" type="submit" name="confirmarconsulta">Confirmar consulta</button>
    </div>
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You really need to read [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), because your current approach is very wrong (insecure and unreliable).

Comment: P.S. Are you expecting `"INSERT INTO angendamentos (horario) VALUES (?)";` to be executed somehow? Because that isn't even assigned to a variable in PHP, never mind sent to the mysql server. You have the same problem with `"INSERT INTO agendamentos (nomemedico) SELECT cpf FROM dadoscadastrocliente";` (in two places). I suggest going and studying mysqli usage examples more carefully, especially the link I just posted above. But your description is not clearly written, so it's hard to tell exactly what you are intending. See also [ask]

Comment: Also, never configure your web app to login to the database as `root`. Root can do whatever it likes, so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Comment: i used this based in others files, that i copied from yt tutorials, im going to read the post that you recommended above, and try to undestand and learn the right way, and then after edit this question or make another one, dont know yet, despite that thanks for you response, advices and pacience.

Comment: I am guessing you have been following some old, obsolete tutorial, and not really even paying close enough attention to that.

Comment: `i copied from yt tutorials`... Sadly, from what I have seen Youtube is a cesspit of mostly terrible programming advice, often written by people who couldn't get a programming job and therefore resorted to trying to attract advertising clicks from unsuspecting novices who don't realise that the video creator only knows about 3 more things than they do. Established books, courses, tutorials and - of course - the PHP documentation are the resources you should be learning from.

Comment: its some indian tutorials that i found from some years ago, the problem is that im trying to do something that i didnt found tutorials for, and based on what you said, what i found and copied from is very bad.

Comment: ```But your description is not clearly written, so it's hard to tell exactly what you are intending.``` Just to clarify what i intended to do, i created a new table,called "agendamentos", and wanted to insert 1 column from 2 differents tables in it and also insert a new value to another column, futhermore wanted to create some way to validate if the informations of the just filled form are correct compared to the other tables but thats not the main priority for now.

Comment: `im trying to do something that i didnt found tutorials for`...all you're doing is submitting a form and executing some SQL queries. There must be 1000 tutorials for that. It doesn't matter if it's a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE query or whatever...the process in PHP is the same: prepare the query, bind the parameters, execute the query. (And then for SELECTs, get the results). As far as I can see, as I mentioned before the main thing you've done wrong in your code (aside from the security problems) is that you simply never execute any of the INSERT queries.

Comment: @ADyson i retyped the question and made some code changes, if you could reevaluate it, i would be grateful.

Comment: Please don't change the question entirely, it makes the whole discussion irrelevant. Your problem is simple, PHP doesn't work this way: you need to run each query separately, with its own prepare, bind_param_end execute. While currently you are just overwriting your statements until the last one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense so it should be something like this? https://imgur.com/a/iYuGpAS

Comment: Yes, exactly this

Comment: @YourCommonSense code now is finally working but im having some problems in the MySQL table: imgur.com/a/2hIy0Lf i wanted to all the informations to appear in the same line, the php is like that: imgur.com/a/AxKEY3R i presume that i used the fetch_all incorrectly, but i didnt understand how should i use it, since im dealing with 3 different querys,wanted to add another "condition" to $sql too, just like the commented part after the first SELECT * FROM(in the body of the question itself), also wanted to thank you for posts in your blog, im looking forward to continue using and learning from it.

Comment: Man. The more I look at your code, the less sense it makes. Why you're using THREE insert statements to insert in ONE table? It must be ONE insert statement. Why you're doing `SELECT nome FROM dadoscadastrocuidador WHERE nome = ?`? How it makes any sense? *Can't you make it just `?`?* I mean, why there is a SELECT query that is selecting the same value? Why can't you make your insert just `INSERT INTO agendamentos (nomemedico,horario,cpfcliente) VALUES (?,?,?)`?

Comment: Besides, you shouldn't add literal values from related tables. Instead of `dadoscadastrocuidador.nome`  you must insert `dadoscadastrocuidador.id` and when selecting, use JOIN to get the actual value from that table. The same goes for dadoscadastrocliente table

Comment: You do seem to be trying to run before you can walk. I wonder if taking a basic course on SQL (without involving php) would be a good idea first.